# Tomcat - Long Time at First Time Start Up

Tags: java, performance, tomcat

I got an issue about Tomcat that
My tomcat startup is quite slow in first time (after reboot my computer), but after shutdown and start again it became quite improved.

There is only one application in the `webapps` folder, and totally need about 200 secs to startup at first time, shutdown and restart change to about 35 secs.

My first thought is there may have some problem with the application.
But weird thing is during some testing, I notice that if I try startup Tomcat with webapps folder empty at first time, then copy my application back to webapps folder, and start again, the time also improved(about 35 secs).
So i start to consume if there are some scan thing for Tomcat.
But after some investigate, I tried add `‘org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip=*.jar’` in the config file, no change...

Other info may help is the time with Tomcat Initialization processed also take much time during first time startup (first time 50s, second lower than 5s).

This issue looks like only exist in Windows, I tried in Mac it works fine for each time (no big different for time need).
My Tomcat version is 8.5, and tried downgrade it to 7.0 still got the same result.

Really appreciate some one can help, drive me crazy for days.

Comment: Take some thread dumps (I suggest 3 dumps ~5 seconds apart) during start-up and see where the time is being spend.

Comment: Thanks so much @MarkThomas, i have tried dump the thread compare the first time and others by jvisualvm, instead of 5 seconds, i tried like 15 secs. But not get the much progress (my dull). But during this i just notice that some different about CPU consume, it looks like the first time not using all of the ability of my CPUs, average Usage about 50%, but second change to almost 100% and this make second quite quick. So my next action will have some investigate on CPU setting, and thanks again for your great thought.